# Fourier (sine) series of a piecewise function

Tags: functions, fourier-series, graphing-functions

I need to find fourier series of the following function:
$$
f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   0 & \text{if $x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$} \\
                                   \pi & \text{if $x\in(\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi)$}
  \end{cases}
$$

and sketch the graph if sum of this series. I have a lot of such functions to transform into fourier series, however I'm not sure how to approach it and all I need to fully understand the topic is one step by step example on this function. I'd be really grateful for any help, as I have trouble understanding how to approach this topic.

I know that 
$$
S_n(x) = \frac{A_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[A_ncos(nx)+B_nsin(nx)]
$$

I also managed to calculate, that 
$$
A_0 = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi f(x)cos(nx)dx
$$
And Bn respectively with sin instead of cos. The problem is, when I try to calculate An, it alternates between $0$, $\frac{1}{n}$ and $-\frac{1}{n}$. I don't really know how to approach this problem.

Comment: First, for a Fourier series your function is supposed to be periodic.  What is the periodic function you will use?  What is the period of the function?  There are formulas for the Fourier coefficients: what are they in this case?  After you write all that in your question, you will be ready to begin!

Comment: I've added all that i understand to the question @GEdgar

Comment: See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSquareWave.html for insight into the derivation of the answer to your question.

Comment: @StevenClark I've managed to find that website by myself, however it didn't help me understand what to do

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier series coefficients of

$$f(\text{x})=\pi\ \theta\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right),\quad 0<x<\pi\tag{1}$$

are given by

$$b_n=\frac{1}{\pi/2}\int\limits_0^{\pi} f(x)\ \sin\left(\frac{\pi\ n\ x}{\pi/2}\right)\,dx\tag{2}=\frac{\cos(\pi\ n)-\cos(2\ \pi\ n)}{n}$$

and the values of these coefficients for $1\le n\le 10$ are as follows:

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 n & b_n \\
 1 & -2 \\
 2 & 0 \\
 3 & -\frac{2}{3} \\
 4 & 0 \\
 5 & -\frac{2}{5} \\
 6 & 0 \\
 7 & -\frac{2}{7} \\
 8 & 0 \\
 9 & -\frac{2}{9} \\
 10 & 0 \\
\end{array}$$

---

Therefore the Fourier series representation of $f(x)$ is as follows:

$$f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^K\frac{2}{2\ k-1}\ \sin\left(\frac{\pi\ (2\ k-1)\ x}{\pi/2}\right)\right),\quad 0<x<\pi\tag{3}$$

---

The figure below illustrates the Fourier series defined in formula (3) above in orange overlaid on the reference function $f(x)$ defined in formula (1) above in blue where formula (3) is evaluated at $K=10$.

[image: Illustration of formula (2) in orange overlaid on top of formula (1) in blue]